# Switch statement keeps using default case no matter what - C beginner

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

//This code is supposed to add or subtract and keep track of four different beer brands with individual ID's. Using -1 does exit, but using any of the ID numbers 1-4 causes the program to execute the defualt case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int inv1;
int inv2;
int inv3;
int inv4;

printf("Pleas enter the beginning inventory of Piels. \n");
scanf("%d", &inv1);
printf("Pleas enter the beginning inventory of Coors. \n");
scanf("%d", &inv2);
printf("Pleas enter the beginning inventory of Bud. \n");
scanf("%d", &inv3);
printf("Pleas enter the beginning inventory of Iron City. \n");
scanf("%d", &inv4);

printf("Please enter the ID number. \n Piels - 1 \n Coors - 2 \n Bud - 3 \n Iron City - 4 \n Enter -1 to exit \n"); 

int id;

scanf("%d", &id);
while( id != -1){

int amount;

    switch (id) {
    case '1': 
         printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
         scanf("%d", &amount);
         inv1 += amount;
         break;
    case '2': 
         printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
         scanf("%d", &amount);
         inv2 += amount;
         break;
    case '3': 
         printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
         scanf("%d", &amount);
         inv3 += amount;
         break;
    case '4': 
         printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
         scanf("%d", &amount);
         inv4 += amount;
         break;
    default:
        printf("Error: That ID Number is not an option. \n");
        break;
                  }


printf("Please enter the ID number. \n Piels - 1 \n Coors - 2 \n Bud - 3 \n Iron City - 4 \n Enter -1 to exit \n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
}
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not well-versed in C, but isn't `id` supposed to be an `int`? your `case`s are enclosed in single quotes

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code (never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.)  Indent after every opening brace '{'.   Un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while. do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line.

Comment: a small thing:  the word 'pleas' is unknown,  suspect you meant 'please'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Remove quotes and try from switch condition

```
 switch (id) {
        case 1: 
             printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
             scanf("%d", &amount);
             inv1 += amount;
             break;
        case 2: 
             printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
             scanf("%d", &amount);
             inv2 += amount;
             break;
        case 3: 
             printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
             scanf("%d", &amount);
             inv3 += amount;
             break;
        case 4: 
             printf("Enter the change in amount. It will be a negative if the amount is sold, or positive if the amount is purchased \n");
             scanf("%d", &amount);
             inv4 += amount;
             break;
        default:
            printf("Error: That ID Number is not an option. \n");
            break;
                      }
```

Comment: Oh duh. I was using my switch statement about chars as an example. I'm dumb. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Since you read your input as integer:

```
scanf("%d", &id); //note the %d
```

Then the `id` will have a value of integer, converted from the `string` which you input in your Console.

```
Example: 
Input: 41 //this is char '4' and '1', having value of 0x34 (52) and 0x31 (49) respectively
Result: id = 41 //(not resulting in char* but value of 41)
```

If you want to use character, then you should do this instead:

```
char id;
scanf(" %c", &id); //note the %c, might also be better if used with early space to avoid \n from the input buffer
```

Such that it will read your input as character

```
Example:
Input: 4 //this is char '4' (having value of 0x34 (52))
Result: id = '4' or id = 52 //not resulting in actual value of 4, but char '4' or value of 52 (0x34)
```

Then your switch:

```
switch(id){
    case '4': //this has actual value of 52 (or 0x34), check ASCII table
        break;
    // and so on, 
}
```

will be fine.

Note that this will limit your option from `'0'-'9'` though, since they are the only available ASCII chars.

So, it is still best to use `scanf("%d", &id);`

Simply remove the `'` in your `switch`:

```
int id;
scanf("%d, &id);
switch(id){
    case 1: //this has actual integer value of 1, not ASCII '1' = 0x31 (or 49)
        break;
    // and so on, will be fine
}
```

Then it will also work.

Comment: @user3386109 true... :) perhaps my answer just add the explanation of why it doesn't work as expected. Best choice would still be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mis-understanding, as shown in the code, between a character value and a integer value.

a character, like '1' has the value 0x31.

while a integer value like 1 has the value 0x00000001.

For the switch/cases, the case values need to be integers, so do not wrap those values in single quotes as those single quotes indicate character literals rather than integer literals.